# Where do new users file bug reports, etc.?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36307/why-cant-i-post-a-question-on-math-stackexchange-com) was posted on MO about not being able to post on math.SE.  While MO wasn't the right place for the question, I have to wonder what is.  New users who are experiencing difficulty using math.SE can't post about it on meta, so where do they turn?  The only thing I can think of is that they have to figure out that it is possible for them to contact the moderators, but nowhere is it explicitly described how to do this.  Maybe something should be added to the FAQ.

Comment: I had the same problem. (The above link is broken.)

Comment: @Pierre: Could you try posting the answer again?

Comment: I just did, and got the same error message.

Comment: @Pierre: I think it's a problem at the back-end. Could you try to login at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and post the problem there (if possible)?

Comment: @KennyTM: I tried, but got the message: "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: users with less than 100 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later."

Comment: @Pierre: I have reported this for you at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61817/some-low-rep-users-cannot-post-anywhere. It seems you can still comment, so please add any detail you think is relevant.

Comment: The question is gone - someone must have deleted it as it was in the wrong place.

Comment: @Pierre: Jeff states it is fixed. Please try answering again.

Comment: It seems to work! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: This seems to be a major bug in the design. The site could be broken only for the new users, and because of low reputation (and knowhow) they won't be able to report it anywhere :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The footer of every single page on the site has a `contact us` link listed in bold.

Comment: Ah, sorry; didn't catch that when I glanced at the page.

Answer (score 3):

The contact info is actually written in ["about"](https://math.stackexchange.com/about)

> ### How can I learn more?
>
> Check out the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq). And if you need to contact us, you can do so at **team@stackexchange.com**.

But I agree, it should present in the FAQ too.

Answer (score 0):

We need to allow people to post on meta with low reputation.

Comment: Low rep users *can* post on meta. Those two users' inability to post here yesterday was a bug.

Comment: When I brought this up in the past it was not said to be a bug.

Comment: @muad: 5 rep is very low already. The bug is Pierre, having 56 rep, cannot post.